# Node util promisify mysql TypeError

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using Node's async/await syntax,
I am trying to promisify a MySql function using Node's util library.

When trying to promisify mysql's begin transaction method,
**I am getting the following error -**

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined
```

**Code snippet -**

```
let connection = requestBody.mysqlConnection;

try {
    let createTransaction = util.promisify(connection.beginTransaction).bind(connection);
    await createTransaction();

    let insertQuery = util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection);
    let queryResponse = await insertQuery(sqlQuery, sqlData);

    await connection.commit();
    await connection.end();

    response.insertId = queryResponse.insertId;
    response.hasError = false;
    return response;
} catch (error) {
    console.log("RDS MySql Error : ", error);

    await connection.rollback();
    await connection.end();

    response.hasError = true;
    response.error = error;
    return response;
}
```

**Error trace -**
[image]

Comment: you should add the sqlquery as well and also a extract of sqldata

Comment: But createTransaction does not take any arguments, right?

Comment: i think you must use `await` in an `async` function only.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your mysql function before to promisify it, take a look on this small example:

```
const util = require('util')

function mysqlFn(params, callbk) {
  callbk(null, true)
}

// bind first to make sure the first param is the callback after promisify the function
const mysqlFnBind = mysqlFn.bind(null, {param: 1})

const mysqlFnAsync = util.promisify(mysqlFnBind)
mysqlFnAsync().then(console.log)
```